# XML: let child-node inherit parent-node namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create some xml nodes runtime using XPath for C#. See XML Below:

```
<Package xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Application>
    <m2:VisualElements>
       <!--- INSERT CHILD NODES HERE WHICH ALSO HAVE NAMESPACE 'm2' ---->
    </m2:VisualElements>
  </Application>
</Package>
```

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
XElement visualElements = doc.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "VisualElements");
visualElements.Add(new XElement(doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + "InitialRotationPreference"));
```

I know that this is wrong since I reference the default namespace, this will result in this being added:

```
<InitialRotationPreference />
```

When I want:

```
<m2:InitialRotationPreference />
```

Is there some way to access the parent-nodes namespace (m2) without "knowing" the prefix or the namespace-url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document root's namespace is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest`.  Use the one from `VisualElements`:

```
XName name = visualElements.Name.Namespace + "InitialRotationPreference"
```

Or specify explicitly:

```
XName name = XName.Get("InitialRotationPreference", 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest");
```

Then add an element with that name:

```
visualElements.Add(new XElement(name));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (Name.Namespace)! The other solution you mentioned however, I explicitly said I didn't want. :) Thanks for quick answer, will accept answer in 5 min!

Comment: @user2422321 oops, missed that bit!  It's an option, anyway!